# Good offline dictionaries for GoldenDict

Tags: dictionary, goldendict

Can someone refer me to some offline dictionaries to use with GoldenDict and how to install/integrate them with it? Preferably English to English dictionaries with large wordbase and phonetic notations for pronunciations, their usage in sentences etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not sure how i found this page, but it has got plenty of popular dictionaries in .bgl format (that can be read by GoldenDict).

- [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzrQwK2v03aKWjlsQ3NsaWJKalU)
- [download.huzheng.orgdict.org/dict.org/](http://download.huzheng.org/dict.org/) or just [download.huzheng.org](http://download.huzheng.org)

from which you can download dictionaries in StarDict format.

Answer (score 9):

There is a whole page dedicated to dictionaries on the official website, [Getting dictionaries for GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/dictionaries.php). I'm not sure if you can get other suggestions here because, as clearly explained on that page, there is a risk of copyright infringements for the non-free dictionaries.

The best offline free English to English dictionary I know is [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/). There is a version of it, specially formatted for GoldenDict, on the [download page](http://goldendict.org/download.php): search for WordNet, download the .zip file, unzip it somewhere and add that folder as a source for dictionary files.

Comment: Most of the offline dicitionaries offered there are either online or dead links.

Comment: WordNet is an offline dictionary and the download is still available. I added a link to the download page and some very basic instructions on how to install it.

Answer (score 5):

## Babylon

**EDIT:** Up to the end of 2019, Babylon Software *used* to offer a large selection of [free `.bgl` dictionaries](https://web.archive.org/web/20191219055153/https://www.babylon-software.com/free-dictionaries/) that work flawlessly with GoldenDict. This was possible due to a loophole in the international intellectual property treaties dealing with databases. Unfortunately, this seems to be no longer the case.

Nonetheless, I have included a [web archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191219055153/https://www.babylon-software.com/free-dictionaries/) to get an idea of what was available. Perhaps, these can still be found in the deep crevices of the Internet. You would typically be looking for `.bgl` or `.dsl` files; most of the times compressed into a `.zip` file.

However, Babylon Software still sells [dictionaries and voice add-ons](https://www.babylon-software.com/add-ons/#about). Both will work with GoldenDict.

Comment: The link is no more accessible. :\

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus Yes, I was already aware of this. I rewrote my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: @SergeStoobandt Thanks for the detailed explanation. I was really wondering why Babylon software stopped offering the dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

I think nobody mentioned it.

Get them at your Ubuntu **Package Manager**!

The standard Ubuntu distribution offers some good dictionaries in the *dictd* format (`dict.dz` extension), which is compatible with GoldenDict. I list some that I found there:

- `dict-wn` the WordReference English Dictionary
- `dict-gcide` the Collaborative International Dictionary of English
- `dict-moby-thesaurus` A large English Thesaurus
- `dict-de-en` A German-English dictionary

There are some more, such as  or `dict-foldoc` or `dict-vera`

### Procedure:

1. Open your Package Manager and search for the specific package or just search the word "dictd" there you'll see listed the possible packages
2. Choose and Install the packages
3. Add the path where the `dict.dz` files are to the GoldenDict Sources (*Edit > Dictionaries > Sources > Files > Add*)

   Usually the path is `/usr/share/dictd`. But if it does not work, search for it yourself:

   1. Update the locate database `sudo updatedb`
   2. Search for the extension `locate dict.dz`

Answer (score 1):

English Wiktionary is probably the best choice. You can download it in StarDict/Dictd format in http://www.dictinfo.com/

You may also consider [Aard Dictionary](http://aarddict.org/) as an alternative to GoldenDict for content coming from Wikimedia sites.

Answer (score 0):

I found some must-have GoldenDict files [here](http://download.huzheng.org/babylon/english/), [here](http://download.huzheng.org/dict.org/), [here](http://download.huzheng.org/babylon/misc/) (The tarball labelled "Wikipedia English - Free Encyclopedia"), and [here](http://download.huzheng.org/bigdict/). **:)**

Download and extract the tarball(s) of your choice. Then *GoldenDict* **>** *Edit* **>** *Dictionaries* **>** *Sources* **>** *Files* **>** *Add* **>** Choose the extracted folder.

Comment: your links are exactly those given by Saasira. I wonder if your answer really brings something new... Consider deleting it ;)